# How to store Javascript value in php variable shown in alert

Tags: javascript, php

How to pass `javascript` variable to `php` variable my code is- I want to store alert value in php variable.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready( function() {

    $( '#container' ).html( '<ul class="filetree start"><li class="wait">' + 'Generating Tree...' + '<li></ul>' );

    getfilelist( $('#container') , 'Sample' );

    function getfilelist( cont, root ) {

        $( cont ).addClass( 'wait' );

        $.post( 'Foldertree.php', { dir: root }, function( data ) {

            $( cont ).find( '.start' ).html( '' );
            $( cont ).removeClass( 'wait' ).append( data );
            if( 'Sample' == root ) 
                $( cont ).find('UL:hidden').show();
            else 
                $( cont ).find('UL:hidden').slideDown({ duration: 500, easing: null });

        });
    }

    $( '#container' ).on('click', 'LI A', function() {
        var entry = $(this).parent();

        if( entry.hasClass('folder') ) {
            if( entry.hasClass('collapsed') ) {

                entry.find('UL').remove();
                getfilelist( entry, escape( $(this).attr('rel') ));
                entry.removeClass('collapsed').addClass('expanded');
                window.alert($(this).attr('rel'))
                $( '#selected_file1' ).text( "Folder:  " + $(this).attr( 'rel' ));
                <?php 
                ?>
            }
            else {

                entry.find('UL').slideUp({ duration: 500, easing: null });
                entry.removeClass('expanded').addClass('collapsed');
            }
        } else {
            $( '#selected_file' ).text( "File:  " + $(this).attr( 'rel' ));


        }
    return false;
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Use AJAX to pass information to the server-side. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming

Answer (score 0):

There is difference between Javascript and PHP, PHP is a server-side script language while Javascript is a client-side script language. See https://www.sqa.org.uk/e-learning/ClientSide01CD/page_18.htm

Use the advantage of AJAX instead for your problem